# CollectionView Cells not showing up On screen

Tags: ios, swift, collections, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is the second time that I have dealt with collection Views, and I cant seem to get my cells to show up on the screen. I have tried dozens of different ways like registering my cells, but I still cant get my cells to show up, And i get the error:  "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" I have delt with this kind of error before, but this time I couldn't figure out exactly what I did wrong. Can someone please help me? any answers would be greatly appreciated.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Here is my view controller code if you need it:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

var eventTitle = ""
var dueDate = ""
var datePosted = ""
var eventDescription = ""

@IBOutlet weak var viewAllThingsToDo: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var viewAllGetItDone: UIButton!

@IBAction func viewAllThingsToDoAction(_ sender: Any) {

    func TtdButtonPressed (dueDate: Date, title: String, datePosted: Date, Description: String?) {


    }

}
@IBOutlet weak var GIDCollectionView: ThingsToDoCollectionView!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "homeToDetailedEvents" {
        let destVc = segue.destination as! DetailedEventsViewController
        destVc.eventTitle = eventTitle
        destVc.dueDate = dueDate
        destVc.datePosted = datePosted
        destVc.eventDescription = eventDescription
    }
}
@IBAction func viewAllGetItDoneAction(_ sender: Any) {

}







}


extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)

    if let myCVC = cell as? ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell {

        if myCVC.GIDTitle != nil {
            myCVC.GIDTitle?.text = "Title"
            print("1Contains a value!")
        } else {
            print("1Doesn’t contain a value.")

        }

        if myCVC.GIDDueDate != nil {
            myCVC.GIDDueDate?.text = "June 17"
            print("2Contains a value!")
        } else {
            print("2Doesn’t contain a value.")

        }
        if myCVC.GIDThumbnail != nil {
            myCVC.GIDThumbnail?.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_7070")
            print("3Contains a value!")
        } else {
            print("3Doesn’t contain a value.")
        }

    }
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
}
}
```

And here is the code for my Collection View Cell:

```
import UIKit

class ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var GIDThumbnail: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var GIDTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var GIDDueDate: UILabel!

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = isSelected ? 1.0 : 0.0
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Seems ok, can you share your project with us? And did you specify reuse identifier in your storyboard?

Comment: Sure thing @Andrew, and yes I did specify my reuse identifier in my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Maybe`collectionview.delegate = self` and `collectionview.dataSource = self` in viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to implement that because I don't find anything named collectionView in my viewDidLoad.

Comment: You have to connect your collection view to your ViewController as an outlet and set your view controller to be the collection's delegate and datasource. eg:

`@IBOutlet weak var myCollection: UICollectionView! `
`override func viewDidLoad(){`
    `super.viewDidLoad()`
    `myCollectionView.delegate = self`
    `myCollectionViewDataSource = self`

`}`

Comment: that worked, Thanks! But now I have a new problem where it gives me the error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' " Do you Know how to fix this error?

Comment: Try to set the cell's class to UICollectionElementKindCell and add `as! UICollectionElementKindCell ` at the end of `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)` like so `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionElementKindCell `. And of course check the cell's identifier

Comment: Im sorry, but I got another error saying "Use of undeclared type 'UICollectionElementKindCell'" On the line of `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionElementKindCell '`

Comment: Do you have a class (a swift file) with that name associated to the cell?

Comment: yes, I do its called "ThingsToDoCollectionViewCell"